# Term for a value that is not equal to one, but can be a zero or positive value

Tags: mathematics

While we can use the term 'non-zero' to identify a value which is positive or negative but not equal to 0, I need a word or a term to identify a value which can be zero or more, but not equal to ONE. I do not believe 'non-one' is widely used.

Eg. - To identify, say (n>1) number of apples, I could say 'Multiple apples'. How do we identify (n=0 | n>1) apples?

I am not sure if the question fits the site. Mathematicians, coders and english language experts, please help!!

Best Regards.

Comment: I'm not aware of a term for this, so I'd just say "zero or more than one" - assuming you're excluding fractions between zero and one. "Non-one" wouldn't work here even if it was widely understood, because it wouldn't exclude negatives.

Comment: Thanks. In a context where 'zero or more'(negatives excluded) is implicit and we are only talking about whole numbers, does 'non-one' make sense? I was wondering if there's a shorter term for this.

Comment: Hello, Ankit. I don't understand (n=0 | n>1); is it an acceptable form of n∈Z: {n>1}⋃{0}? ////  I think you're stuck with 'n is a non-negative integer other than one'. Note that 'whole numbers' and 'natural numbers' are ill-defined, some people including zero and others not.

Comment: There isn’t going to be a common word for this because this isn’t a common need. If you can think of a real world context where such a constraint exists, you could start your search there.

Comment: You might have been able to get away with *all but one*, except that it already has a different, established, meaning.

Comment: ... and 'non-unitary' should be avoided, as it already has a different meaning in maths.

Comment: Thanks folks, I guess we can conclude that the term in question does not exist. I guess I'll just go ahead with 'zero or more than one' for now. A bit too long, but it will make do. Thanks for the help